# Ruby on Rails: Create doesn't work. Data doesn't insert to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Two simple model:

Record

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    validates :title, presence: true,
                            length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Comment

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record
end
```

in viewer

```
<h2>Add a comment: </h2>
<%= form_for([@record, @record.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
       <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

in controller

```
def create
    @record = Record.find(params[:record_id])
    @comment = @record.comments.create(comment_params)
    logger.debug "comment check: #{@comment.attributes.inspect}"
    redirect_to record_path(@record)
end
```

Logger information:

```
I, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.802139 #20539]  INFO -- : Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
I, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.802236 #20539]  INFO -- : Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
I, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.802300 #20539]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"12u1/KgN8baCy8Jn/TJi3Ux7m258FZPfraHGUhl9WnM=", "comment"=>{"commenter"=>"qwe", "body"=>"asdsa"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "record_id"=>"4"}
I, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.802338 #20539]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"12u1/KgN8baCy8Jn/TJi3Ux7m258FZPfraHGUhl9WnM=", "comment"=>{"commenter"=>"qwe", "body"=>"asdsa"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "record_id"=>"4"}
D, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.807062 #20539] DEBUG -- :   Record Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "records".* FROM "records"  WHERE "records"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
D, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.807138 #20539] DEBUG -- :   Record Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "records".* FROM "records"  WHERE "records"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
D, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.810514 #20539] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.810599 #20539] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.821927 #20539] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  commit transaction
D, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.822023 #20539] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  commit transaction
D, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.822159 #20539] DEBUG -- : comment check: {"id"=>nil, "commenter"=>"qwe", "body"=>"asdsa", "record_id"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil}
D, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.822201 #20539] DEBUG -- : comment check: {"id"=>nil, "commenter"=>"qwe", "body"=>"asdsa", "record_id"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil}
I, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.822667 #20539]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/records/4
I, [2014-06-26T14:13:49.822714 #20539]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/records/4
```

When I create comment, data doesn't write to database any suggestion?
By the way, why each logger information has double output?

Comment: So I've been screwing around with this particular problem and I encountered something strange. When attempting to create a Comment by itself (`Comment.create`) it actually creates a new `Record` instead. I had to remove the `belongs_to :record` association to prevent that from happening and I have no idea why it isn't working right now. Very very odd.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments` to your `Record` model

Comment: also, which controller is it that is actually doing processing? The form/logic you have looks like its for the `records_controller` but the logger says `comments_controller`

Answer (score 1):

Have you captured anything in the variable comment_params? Don't you need to do something like comment_params = params[:comment] or something like that? I think comment_params is nil when you drop it into your create method (although I may be wrong).

```
def create
  @record = Record.find(params[:record_id])
  @comment = @record.comments.create(params[:comment])

  redirect_to record_path(@record)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, change `comment.create` to `comment.build`, so that the relationship gets created.  Also, pass only the params for the comment:

```
def create
  @record = Record.find(params[:record_id])
  @comment = @record.comments.build(params[:comment])
  logger.debug "comment check: #{@comment.attributes.inspect}"
  redirect_to record_path(@record) 
end
```